# Force optimizer to not make any assumptions about contents of char array

Tags: c, gcc

How can I force gcc's optimizer not to make any assumptions about the contents of a char array inside my code? As far as I understood, this should be possible with the `volatile` keyword but it doesn't seem to work.

Take a look at the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    volatile unsigned char magickey[] =  "\xDE\xAD\xC0\xDE\xC0\xDE\xCA\xFE\xC0\xCA\xC0\x1A";    
    volatile unsigned int val;

    //  printf("TEST: %p\n", magickey); 

    val = (magickey[0] << 24) | (magickey[1] << 16) | (magickey[2] << 8) | magickey[3];

    printf("TEST2: %x\n", val);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile the executable like this:

```
gcc -O3 test.c
```

I want to be able to open the executable in a hex editor and change the first 4 bytes of the `magickey` char array and `val` should contain the bytes I hex'ed into the char array by modifying the executable.

This works only as long as the first call to `printf` is deactivated (as in the code shown above). As soon as I activate the first call to `printf`, however, the program always prints `TEST2: deadc0de` no matter which values I wrote into the executable using a hex editor.

This is confusing me. The first call to `printf` seems completely harmless because it just prints the address of the char array. I don't see why activating this line affects the optimizer in any way.

So I must be doing something wrong. What can I do to force the optimizer not to make any assumptions about the contents of the `magickey` char array so that I can fill it with arbitrary bytes after compilation by hacking the executable using a hex editor and the bytes I wrote into it using a hex editor are correctly copied to `val`? `volatile` doesn't really seem to do the job.

Comment: When you compile with `gcc -O3` it's possible that it's being optimized to the point that the print statement is hardcoded in to print `deadc0de` later in the application. See if hex editing with `-O2` or `-O1` flags give you the same result.

Comment: Are you declaring `magickey` as a global variable or a local variable? The question should be edited to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is that rare occasion where I would suspect a compiler bug..

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's not a bug, it's a feature. Specifically, gcc values optimization above all else, even if it means producing code that doesn't do what the programmer wants it to do (provided of course that the optimization is not specifically prohibited by the C specification).

Comment: @user3386109 Well, it is hardly conforming with http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p7 . Unless my understanding of the lawyer language is failing me here. changing the binary can be considered as "*modified in ways unknown to the implementation*". Or it may not. Probably this is the hole... Once you modify the compiler output, you void it's warranty :)

Comment: @user3386109: Well, it is the complete program. I just cut out the function declaration. I've edited my post now to include a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: So is there anything I can do about it? Or should I just put that particular code in a source file of its own and compile this file with all optimizations turned off?

Comment: @Andreas You are modifying the binary, so it is no more a *valid* compiler-generated file anymore. So you can't lawfully demand anything from it. You can come up with a solution which works just *here and now*, but you can't guarantee the same will work in the future.

Comment: @EliSadoff: Yes, using `-O2` instead solves the problem but that's not the solution I'm looking for. I specifically want to keep `-O3` but the optimizer should be forced not to make any assumptions about the contents of `magickey`.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is that the array is a local variable. Therefore, gcc knows that external actors (e.g. hardware, interrupt routines, other threads) have no access to that array. So the only way that array can get modified is by passing the address of the array to some function, e.g. `printf`. Try defining an empty function `void foo(char *unused){}`, pass `magickey` to that function, and see what gcc does. Or just declare `magickey` as a global variable (so that it's theoretically accessible by hardware, interrupts and other threads).

Comment: @user3386109 By declaring an object `volatile` you are telling that the access method is *unknown for the implementation*. So no, it can't know that no access to if from elsewhere..

Comment: @user3386109: Great, using a global variable instead indeed solves the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EugeneSh. The problem with 6.7.3p7 is that is says, see section 5.1.2.3, and then 5.1.2.3 says, see the rest of the document. That leaves a lot of room for debate.

Comment: @user3386109 Sure. But the bottom line here is - do not rely on this behavior.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I know modifying the binary is evil but still I was wondering whether there is a way to get what I want. user3386109's suggestion works just fine. Maybe it won't work forever but right now it does what I need.

Comment: @Andreas You're welcome! Glad that worked for you.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think you can rely on a volatile global variable not being optimized, right? The behavior that's unexpected is that a volatile local variable can be optimized. That's something you should not rely on, I agree.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Don't get me wrong, I'm not defending `gcc`. In fact, I strongly disagree with some of the choices that the `gcc` team made regarding optimizations. My current favorite joke: the code for the [Mars lander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schiaparelli_EDM_lander#Loss_of_the_lander) must have been compiled with gcc. Why? Because the parachute was released early, and the retrorockets fired for 3 seconds instead of 30. Obviously `gcc` optimized the code to make it run faster.

Comment: @user3386109 I mean that `volatile` is not a magical word. Simply consider the above code, and think that for some reason GCC is deciding to *copy* the initializer array elsewhere, and the use it just from that new location only. It does not break the `volatile` semantics, but gives the exact behavior OP is getting.